# cleanest way to build and reverse list (or multi-slice a list) in python

Tags: python

I have two lists, one that is letters and the other is numerical values.  I need to find the indices of the `n` highest numerical values and return the letters with the matching indices, in descending order of numerical value.  That is, if I have a list like `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` and another like `[1 3 9 6 0]` and I filter on the top three values, I should get `['c', 'd', 'b']` as my result.  This code does what I want:

```py
import numpy as np

def func():
    letters = list(map(chr, range(97, 123)))
    vals = np.array(np.random.random(26))
    n = 5

    res = [letters[i] for i in np.argsort(vals)[-n:][::-1]]

    return res

func()
```

but the `[-n:][::-1]` seems kind of kludgy.  I couldn't figure out a way to combine them into one slice operation that would work; I could  move the `[::-1]` to modify `res` after it's built, but that doesn't seem a whole lot cleaner.  Is there a better way to do this?  Unless I missed something, `argsort` only works in ascending order and I didn't see an equivalent to do descending order; if I could reverse that I'd be 95% of the way there.

Comment: if you negate the array, the values become negative..can get rid of the flipping that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A faster alternative, and cleaner in my opinion, oppose to using sort 
that has a time complexity of `O(n log n)`, is to use a [heap](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html#module-heapq):

```
import heapq
from operator import itemgetter

letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
counts = [1, 3, 9, 6, 0]

result = [letter for letter, _ in heapq.nlargest(3, zip(letters, counts), key=itemgetter(1))]
print(result)
```

Using a heap gives you a complexity of `O(n log k)` that is a lot faster if `k << n`.

Comment: This should be `O(n log k)`, not `O(k log n)`. You are inserting `n` elements into a heap of size `k`.

Comment: For reference, here is the source code: *"In the worst case, the input data is reversed sorted so that every new element must be inserted in the heap: comparisons = 1.66 * k + log(k, 2) * (n - k)"* https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/heapq.py#L445

Comment: By the way, it's a good solution, it's definitely good that somebody is paying attention to efficiency. You can avoid the `key=itemgetter(1)` by doing `zip(counts, letters)` instead. With that I think it's cleaner than `sorted`.

Comment: @kaya3, I tried doing `zip(counts, letters)` and removing the `key=` argument, but that returned the numeric values from counts, not the letters.

Comment: @jml you have to change the destructuring assignment from `letter, _` to `_, letter` if you change their order in the tuple.

Comment: You're right, I missed that.  Looking at it that way, heap is indeed a good solution, even for the smaller use case.

Answer (score 3):

You can `zip` two lists and sort the list of tuples:

```
>>> letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> vals = [1, 3, 9, 6, 0]
```

then

```
>>> sorted(zip(vals, letters))[-3:]
[(3, 'b'), (6, 'd'), (9, 'c')]
```

therefore

```
>>> [v for k, v in sorted(zip(vals, letters))[-3:]]
['b', 'd', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, `lst[-n:][::-1]` is equivalent to `lst[:-n-1:-1]` as a single slice:

```py
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> a[-4:][::-1]
[9, 8, 7, 6]
>>> a[:-5:-1]
[9, 8, 7, 6]
>>> a[-4:][::-1] == a[:-4-1:-1]
True
```

Answer (score 1):

for the sake of a different approach...this is very easy in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'letters':letters,'vals':vals})
n = 3
res = df[df['vals'].eq(df['vals'].nlargest(n))].sort_values(by='vals',ascending=False)
```

output:

```
   letters      vals
18       s  0.958361
4        e  0.934126
22       w  0.877045
```

fyi - using the full letters and vals defined in your original code